# Status bar using .pack doesn't extend past my .grid frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've finally dove into programming and just recently started wrapping my head around classes/subclasses/inheritance etc.

**Problem**
My root.geometry is set to 500x500, but my status bar does not extend past the grid frame I have for the labels at the top of the GUI. The result is a little mini-status bar under what is meant to be on the bottom of the entire window.

```py
from tkinter import * #Yes -- I know this crowds the namespace -- I'll change it later

UPDATE_RATE = 1000

class Application(Frame):
    global beginupdate
    beginupdate = False

    def __init__(self, master):

        """ Initialize the frame """
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.updater()

    def create_widgets(self):

        # ********** Status Bar **********
        self.status_frame = Frame(self)
        self.healthstatus = StringVar()
        self.status = Label(self.status_frame, textvariable=self.healthstatus, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.status_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=TRUE)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=TRUE)

    def update_something1(self):
        if beginupdate:
            donothing()
        print('Updated')

    def updater(self):
        global beginupdate

        self.update_something1()
        beginupdate = True
        self.after(UPDATE_RATE, self.updater)


def donothing():
    print("ok ok I won't")


root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I spent nearly 4 hours trying to get this silly status bar worked out. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: If would help if you reduced the code down to a [mcve]. I see a lot of code that seems unrelated to the question being asked. For example, I recommend removing almost everything except an empty toolbar, a main window, and the statusbar. Get those working before adding any other widgets. You're trying to solve too many problems at once.

Comment: Geez, was a downvote really necessary to a first time poster. I did all I can to reduce this down. How is any of it unrelated? This is the stripped down class that just does the bare functionality intended. 

If I remove that core functionality, it of course works as intended. That's how it was before. 

The problem arose merely when I moved this status bar in the the class for initialization and the code inside the class should make it clear why I need it there and not outside (updating the labels/buttons which are on grid() and the status bar which is on pack().

Comment: A minimal example means people can simply copy & paste your code, run and get the error you received, and that includes imports too.

Comment: Ah, I see. My apologies for misunderstanding. 

I figured the question was so basic someone would probably just know off the top of their head. I'll try editing something tomorrow (been up 36 hours)

Comment: None of the menubar code is necessary to duplicate the problem. Also, I'm pretty sure none of the labels inside the main window are necessary to  duplicate the problem. Also, your code references `donothing` and `balance` which doesn't exist. And, you're missing imports. All of that means that nobody can reproduce your problem, which lowers the quality of the question. If you want help, you need to do everything you possibly can to help people who are volunteering to help you. The votes are a way to let you know the question needs improvement.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've deleted all the stuff you asked, and added the import line, so it should be a straight copy/paste at this point if you have Python 3.7 running.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you've created widgets that don't have anything in them, so their natural size is going to be only a few pixels tall and wide. Even though you're forcing the window to be 500x500, nothing is visible because they are all very small.

The main reason for this is that you're using `grid`, and by default `grid` will only use the smallest amount of space necessary to display its contents. Thus, your tiny frame with a tiny label appears in just a couple pixels in the upper left (row 0, column 0) location of the root window.

My personal rule of thumb is to always use `pack` if you are only putting one widget inside another, such as the case of putting your `app` inside the root window. You can solve this with `grid` by giving row zero and column zero a weight, but that requires a total of three lines when `pack` requires only one.

So, step one is to remove this line of code from `__init__`:

```
    self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
```

I think it's a bad practice for one widget (in your case,`Application`) to place itself inside another. Instead, the code that creates `Application` should be responsible for adding it to the root window.

To do that, add the following line immediately after you create `app` and right before you call `mainloop`:

```
app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

At this point you will won't see anything, because there's nothing to see. Well, that's not entirely true -- the root window is black but all you'll see is white (or gray) because that's the color of the status label and the frame it is in. Plus, you've requested that the status label completely fill its frame, and you've requested that the frame fills the window.

You can see this by putting a string in your label. For example, add this after creating `self.healthstatus`:

```
self.healthstatus.set("Hello, World!")
```

You should see the message in the vertical middle of the screen, and aligned to the left.

As I wrote earlier, you've requested the status label and frame to fill its window. I doubt that you really want that. Change how you call pack on those two widgets to be this:

```
self.status_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x', expand=False)
self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x', expand=False)
```

Notice that this will prevent those widgets from expanding to fill all the space, and instead only fill in the x direction while remaining at the bottom of the window.

Here is a working version, though I've removed the unnecessary `updater` function since it's unrelated to the layout problem:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.status_frame = Frame(self)
        self.healthstatus = StringVar()
        self.healthstatus.set("Hello, World!")
        self.status = Label(self.status_frame, textvariable=self.healthstatus, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)

        self.status_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x', expand=False)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x', expand=False)

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: window screenshot]

Comment: The line:
```
app.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```
fixed the issue almost entirely, albeit the unused space is now gray when combined with the code I removed, and app.config(bg='black') doesn't seem to affect it.

I set root to 500x500 mostly because I want to keep it expanded between edits.

There are other ways to work around this, but the fundamental fact is I don't understand how to fix this, and it bothers me when I don't understand how to do it, even if there is another approach.